# Oracle Parameter Issue (Using OR Opeator)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

If I execute both query individually it is not taking 4sec to get data, but when combine both I see query is deadslow. Any help much appreciated

Query1:

Select Med_Number,Med_Code,Member_Name,DOB FROM Med
WHERE Med.Med_Code=:Med_Code    
Query2:

Select Red_Number,Red_Name,Red_Code FROM Red 
WHERE Red.Red_Code =:Red_Code 


Final One:Im passing one value at a time

Select Med_Number,Member_Name,Red_Number,Red_Name FROM Med M
LEFT JOIN Red R ON M.Med_Number=R.Red_Number
Where (Med.Med_Code=:Med_Code) OR (Red.Red_Code=:Red_Code)

Comment: It would be extremely helpful to know the relationship between MED and RED (e.g., for every MED there are 0 or more RED) and the primary key and relevant foreign keys.

Comment: Yes True for one Med there are more Red or 0

Comment: You really need to put the relationship information in the question by clicking the [edit] button. I highly recommend you use something like sqldeveloper to transpose the real table's primary keys and foreign keys into your post.

Comment: Your combined query is significantly different from the individual queries. In the combined query you've introduced a join on MED_NUMBER/RED_NUMBER. Are these columns indexed on their respective tables? Also, given the filter conditions in the WHERE clause it appears that may you want to use a FULL OUTER JOIN instead of a LEFT OUTER JOIN. Best of luck.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I can get that, I don't have permissions to do that

Comment: Yes Bob, I see index is exist in respective tables, but I don't see relation found

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the execution plan for all 3 statements, you'll figure it out. If you're not interested in figuring it out and you must execute only one query, then you can execute this, using src to determine which rows below to which row source assuming you have to know the difference and assuming the numbers and names are suitably equivalent data types:

```
Select 1 src, Med_Number,Member_Name,DOB
FROM Med
WHERE Med.Med_Number=:Med_Number
UNION ALL
Select 2 src, Red_Number,Red_Name, null
FROM Red 
WHERE Red.Red_Number=:Red_Number
```

Of course, if the data types are equivalent and DOB is not allowed to be null, then this would suffice

```
Select Med_Number,Member_Name,DOB
FROM Med
WHERE Med.Med_Number=:Med_Number
UNION ALL
Select Red_Number,Red_Name, null
FROM Red 
WHERE Red.Red_Number=:Red_Number
```

Comment: Good idea but only thing, if user pass 2 parameters in frontend, for suppose Med number is 1 and red number 2, he will end up getting two records. But only one result should be fetch from frontend. I hope you got it .questions let me know. Thanks.

Comment: @KotiRaavi You significantly changed the meaning of your question when you edited the SQL statement text.

Comment: Yes apologies, I'm using different column to Join :(, I got to know from someone.

Answer (score 0):

As you join your two tables on m.Med_number = R.Red_number, you don't need 2 parameters.

```
Select Med_Number,Member_Name,Red_Number,Red_Name FROM Med M
LEFT JOIN Red R ON M.Med_Number=R.Red_Number
Where M.Med_Number=:Number;
```

Comment: Opps Sorry,Joining is different column , let me update statement